# default value for argument

Tags: ruby, sinatra

```
require 'sinatra'

index = ->(page=0) do
    "#{page}\n"
end

get '/p/:page', &index
get '/', &index

p index.call()
p index.call(5)
```

Well, on startup this prints "0\n" and "5\n", but when I access /p/5 "0" is rendered. Why is that? And how can I make it right?

Comment: Please specify your environment. Here @ `Sinatra/1.4.3`/`Ruby 2.0` it works as expected (renders `5` for `/p/5`.)

Comment: `sinatra 1.4.3, ruby 1.9.3, windows 7` -- works as for OP -- always return 0 value (or whatever you assign to default value in `index = ->(page=0) do`). If I remove default assignment -- everything works OK. So, it looks like it somehow binded to default value...

Comment: My environment:

    ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i486-linux]
    sinatra (1.4.2)

Comment: Upgraded to `sinatra 1.4.3`, still the same. I'm going to compile ruby 2.

Comment: Ok, with ruby 2 it works.